# I have problem with my JWT authentification at the /api/me endpoint

Tags: symfony, jwt, nuxt.js, api-platform.com

I have create API Plateforme with NuxtJS in front, I have setup nuxt Auth with JWT authentification from my api plateforme, in local all is good but when I check my login and my register in production I have a problem in my /api/me response :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV67J.png)

I dont understand why, thats my configuration :

ActionController with :

```
 /**
 * @return User
 */
public function fn_me(): User
{
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $this->getUser();

    return $user;
}
```

User Entity :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYHBn.png)

And my routes :

```
api_me:
path: '/api/me'
methods: ['GET']
defaults:
    _controller: '\App\Controller\ActionController::fn_me'
    _api_resource_class: 'App\Entity\User'
    _api_collection_operation_name: 'collName_api_me'
```

Thanks for yout help !

Comment: You should check which configuration is different for your dev and prod environments. There's probably some difference there. Also check your PHP.ini and whether there are differences between local and prod. Make sure also that PHP can write sessions in production. (e.g. problem with sessions occurs if there is no more space left on the server's drive)

Comment: When my site in http it works

Comment: Maybe there are some stricter rules used for cookies when you're on https? When you're on prod, did you check whether the session cookie is properly persisted in the browser and is sent to the backend with requests?

Comment: Where can I find that

Comment: In the browser using dev tools. Check what cookies are there when you're on localhost and whether you have the same when on prod. In the network tab you can check whether those cookies are being sent with requests to your prod app.

Comment: The request who work : https://prnt.sc/1uvx6qn

Comment: The request who failed :https://prnt.sc/1uvx9bn

Comment: Ok, so I see that you don't use cookies but Bearer tokens for sessions (sorry I missed that in the original question!). So, are you sure that those tokens are validated with proper keys in the prod environment?

Comment: Yes of course i have regenerate my keys and they work because when i'm login i have the good token, the problem is only when i do /api/me endpoint

Comment: I finaly found the solution, i have overwrite apache configuration and rewrite http Auhtorization : RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]  and its work well

Comment: Oh, great :) You can add it as an answer and accept it, so that people know that the problem was resolved.